# EC2 AWS SSL issue in Wordpress for load assets

Tags: wordpress, ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2

I have a wordpress blog in AWS that uses http.

Now I instaled a SSL certificate so I can use https.
All http://www.mysite.com works fine. All content loads and is perfect.

When I use https://www.mysite.com, all assets (images, css, js,..) are not loaded and got a console error that the server can't find in https.

Does anyone know a possible solution for this?

Installed mod_sll, restarted Apache, update yum, open port 443.... But nothing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't properly setup the SSL virtual host. if you use default ssl.conf in apache, make sure you add ServerName and ServerAlias accordingly.

If it still didn't work. Please backup your ssl.conf first and delete all the lines below

`## SSL Virtual Host Context` in ssl.conf and put following content in ssl.conf or as a new file in `sites-enabled` if you're using debian based.

Also dont forget to run `netstat -nltp` and see if port 443 is listing by apache. If not add `listen 443` in your httpd.conf or ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine  on
    SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT

    ## /etc/httpd/ssl/ replace with the directory which contains your PrivateKey, 
    ## Certificate and Bundle file(if available)

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.crt/your_domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.key/your_domain.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.crt/bundle.crt

    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
    ServerAdmin youremail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain.com/htdocs

    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/yourdomain.com/htdocs"

    <Directory "/var/www/yourdomain.com/htdocs" >
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
            allow from all
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/yourdomain-access_log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/yourdomain-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```